# The maximum eigenvalue of the sum of two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there are two matrix $A$ and $B$. The components of each matrix is non-negative.

And 
$$Ax_1=\lambda_1 x_1  $$ where $\lambda_1$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

Similarly

$$Bx_2=\lambda_2 x_2  $$ where $\lambda_2$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $B$.

Let $C = A+B$

And 
$$Cx=\lambda x  $$ where $\lambda$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $C$.

From wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), it shows that $$\left\| A+B \right\|\le \left\| A \right\|+\left\| B \right\|$$
The maximum eigenvalue is 2 norm. So no matter the components are negative or not, $$\lambda\le \lambda_1+\lambda_2$$

Comment: If $x$ is a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$, then $\lambda\leq \lambda_1,\ \lambda\leq \lambda_2$.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay I think you meant $$\lambda x=Cx=Ax+Bx\leq\lambda_1x+\lambda_2x,$$ and hence $\lambda\leq\lambda_1+\lambda_2$.

Comment: @AD Yes, yes, I wrote it incorrectly, thinking something else.

Comment: Is this from a book? May I ask which book you are reading?

Comment: @AD. hi,It is not from a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By [Gelfand's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Theorem_.28Gelfand.27s_formula.2C_1941.29), if $\|\cdot\|$ is any matrix norm, then $\rho(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$. Now, simply take $\|\cdot\|$ as the maximum row sum norm, i.e. $\|A\|=\max\limits_i\sum_j|a_{ij}|$. Since both $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative, we have $0\le A^n\le(A+B)^n$ entrywise. Hence the result follows.